# How can a pass a body with my POST and DELETE request using Http Web Request

Tags: c#, api, httpwebrequest

I have a Generic method SendRequest that sends request to get the OAuth token at the run time and then also uses to Send my request to the server. I have few POST and DELETE call that takes a body of list or a string. But I do not know how to set it. I know how to send the Json and by serialize it but I am having trouble how to add a body when its just a string or a list type.

```
  public HttpWebResponse SendRequest(string postData = "", Authentication.TokenType tokenType = Authentication.TokenType.Valid)
        {
            var messageBody = postData;
            var strResponseValue = string.Empty;

            var request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(EndPoint);
            if (EndPoint == StringBuilderUtil.GenerateRequestURL("token"))
            {
                request.ContentType = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded";
                request.Host = "identity-authority." + 
              ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["TestEnvironment"];
                Token = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["GenericSpecialCode"];
            }
            else
            {
                request.ContentType = "application/json";
                Token = Authentication.ChooseToken(tokenType);
            }

            if (HttpMethod == HttpVerb.POST)
                request.Headers.Add(HttpRequestHeader.AcceptEncoding, "gzip,deflate");

            // Add some headers that are common to all calls.
            request.KeepAlive = true;
            request.Headers.Add("Authorization", AuthType.ToString() + " " + Token);
            request.Method = HttpMethod.ToString();
            request.Headers.Add("Cache-Control", "no-cache");

            var lbPostBuffer = Encoding.Default.GetBytes(messageBody);

            request.ContentLength = lbPostBuffer.Length;
            if (HttpMethod == HttpVerb.POST)
            {
                var PostStream = request.GetRequestStream();
                PostStream.Write(lbPostBuffer, 0, lbPostBuffer.Length);
                PostStream.Close();
            }

            return request.GetResponse() as HttpWebResponse;
        }

[![enter image description here][1]][1]


  [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/ec6hh.png
```

Answer (score 0):

> how to add a body when its just a string or a list type.

If you are sending a string you don't have to do much apart from encoding and putting it into the stream.

list type goes the same way as object. You have to serialize it first.

There is logic already for the last two things.

```cs
var lbPostBuffer = Encoding.Default.GetBytes(messageBody);

            request.ContentLength = lbPostBuffer.Length;
            if (HttpMethod == HttpVerb.POST)
            {
                var PostStream = request.GetRequestStream();
                PostStream.Write(lbPostBuffer, 0, lbPostBuffer.Length);
                PostStream.Close();
            }
```

I assume serialization happens before calling `SendRequest` method and if you are using Newtonsoft.Json it can be done with `JsonConvert.SerializeObject`

Comment: my body data is a string sometimes its  a list. I am sending it as a string in the sendrequest method but its giving me a 400 bad request

Comment: Is it specifying any validation errors in bad request? It can be anything